# Converting AC signal into PWM

Tags: analog, pwm

I have been attempting to convert an AC audio signal into PWM in order to design a class D audio amplifier.

I have made several attempts, but none of them have been successful due to significant issues.

**Diode Method**
I tried using diodes to determine the current half cycle of the signal, and then employed a timer IC and a comparator to modulate the signal into PWM.

- Issue: The presence of diodes causes a voltage drop, leading to distortion in the signal.

**AC Signal with DC Offset**
Another approach I attempted involved adding a DC offset to the AC signal and then feeding it into a comparator and a 555 timer IC for modulation.

- Issue: Depending on the volume of the AC signal, the PWM output causes a slight popping sound from the speaker due to the offset.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving these issues and finding a successful method for converting AC audio to PWM for my class D audio amplifier design.

Comment: Welcome! What topology are you running? Please show at least a block diagram.

Comment: Try the LTC6992

Comment: The LTC6992 requires a signal ranging from 0 to 1 volt. Please refrain from suggesting chips without reading their datasheet or fully understanding my question. My inquiry pertains to how I can effectively manage the AC signal that goes below 0 volts.

Comment: In a first attempt you create a sawtooth signal (best > 100 kHz) in the same voltage range as your audio signal has. If you feed a comparator with the sawtooth and the audio you get the desired PWM. The PWM duty cycle without audio signal must be exact 50% to avoid DC current in the speaker, which is critical. There are better implementations inside digital audio amplifiers.

Comment: @RayyanKhan, I’d suggest Mr Andy understands your problem better than you do, so don’t be too quick to reject his suggestions. With audio it is common to use a series capacitor to ‘shift’ the AC signal so it fits within a unipolar voltage range ie: in the case of a 0 to 1V input range, 0.5V is the virtual zero volts of the AC signal.

Comment: Everyone keeps ignoring the most important problem which is that AC audio is not DC. Shifting the AC up results in the speaker possibly being popped up

Comment: We’re not ignoring it. Break open any product doing class D amplification and/or some DSP and you’ll find DC offset to bring your symmetrical AC signal up to positive only domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Andy's suggestion (who clearly understands your problem and your solution better than you do), you take your peak to peak audio signal and scale it down to 1 volt peak to peak. Now, add +0.5V DC offset to bring the signal into the input operating range of the LTC6992. The output of the LTC6992 generates an output PWM signal proportional to the input signal. Use this output to drive your output stage (push-pull totem poll or what have you). This is the "first guess circuit" without knowing additional constraints. Of course with additional circuitry this can be made more efficient. And you can add a DC servo to remove bias and do a few other tricks to enhance performance. But I suggest you start here until you become more familiar with this circuit - you're clearly having an issue with how to deal with a signal that goes below ground and the idea of shifting the signal up seems foreign to you.

I don't understand your "Diode Method" or what you were attempting to do so I won't comment on that.

The slight popping in your "AC signal with DC Offset" solution is most likely due to cross distortion or clipping in your signal chain; a DC offset on the output, or the input for that matter, wouldn't cause slight popping as the offset is static and the popping is due to some transient effect. However, you can overheat the voice coil with a high enough DC offset on the output, but this would be a malfunction of the amplifier and not a design characteristic.

Andy, Jens, Kartman, and myself are not ignoring the most important part about the audio being AC and not DC - we understand the situation perfectly well. It's quite reasonable to shift the signal to get it to fall within the operating range of the next stage - in this case 0V-1V. If the overall circuit is designed properly, the speaker never "knows" this shift took place and only "sees" the speaker-level AC signal centered at ground.